# How should I power multiple RPi 3 units from a beefy power supply?

Tags: pi-3, power, power-supply, electronics

I have to power 20 Raspberry Pi 3 units from a few 5V 10A power DC power supplies. I have little experience in electronics. The RPis can be up to 1.5m apart from one another. A friend of mine suggested I use four such power supplies and create a power circuit for each 5 RPis. I am essentially looking to have multiple 5V lines passing through the ceiling and individual lines come about 1-2m down to each RPi. The things I need help with are the following:

- What type of wire I would need
- I need a sturdy connection from the main 5V line to the RPi (which I want to be able to temporarily disconnect if need be) and I am not sure - here I was thinking about having some kind of sockets on the main 5V line, perhaps some kind of screw-in connector
- How many power supplies do I need and what is this dependent on (length, thickness of cable; etc)

I expect the individual units to draw less than 1.5A at any given point, as they will only power an accelerometer and their onboard Wi-Fi and BLE.

Thank you!

Comment: how are you powering one RPi now?

Comment: I am using either a 5v 2A powerbank or the above mentioned PSU with some wires duct taped together.

Comment: PC ATX power supply.  Finding 5v 20a should be easy. Buy molex Y, cut off the male end and have 2 female ends for 2 different Pi's.  You could then attach the 5v wires to the 5v wires in a usb cable you cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm not a 100% sure so please correct me in the comments.

I think you could use 4 USB hubs/splitters that would connect to 4 10A bricks. You would then get 20 Micro USB cables to connect to the individual Pis from the Hubs. Because you have a 10A Power supply, it would supply 2A each to the Pis.

Another solution, if you're willing to buy a power supply, is to get 2-3 bricks like this:

[image: Product Image]